# Visual Studio Online Dashboard for Multiple Projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm having trouble figuring out whether this exists.

I've got multiple projects in Visual Studio Online, and each one of these has its own dashboard where you can add widgets to see useful stuff like build progress.

I'm wondering whether I can use one central dashboard to see this information for all of my projects, but I can't find it. Anyone had any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  In TFS (and VSTS) you have Collections (accessible in TFS but not accessible in VSTS), then Team Projects, then Projects/Repositories.  In TFS OnPrem you can do some 'magic' to build queries that cross the Team Project boundaries but it's not supported or even recommended.

If you are looking for a way to have information about multiple Team Projects, for an OnPrem version of TFS you would use SQL Report Server.  This option is not available with VSTS so your only option is Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the use-case for Teams. Teams allow you to, within a single team project, manage and report on multiple simultaneous development efforts, including reporting across team boundaries and in aggregate. The current recommendation is to keep everything contained in a single team projects and use teams instead.